# How to set an image into a circle?

Tags: android

I found the following code in one of the prvious topics:

```
    public Bitmap getLetterTile(String displayName, String key, int width, int height) {
        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final char firstChar = displayName.trim().charAt(0);

        final Canvas c = mCanvas;
        c.setBitmap(bitmap);
        c.drawColor(pickColor(key));

        mFirstChar[0] = Character.toUpperCase(firstChar);
        mPaint.setTextSize(mTileLetterFontSize);
        mPaint.getTextBounds(mFirstChar, 0, 1, mBounds);
        c.drawText(mFirstChar, 0, 1, width / 2, height / 2 + (mBounds.bottom - mBounds.top) / 2, mPaint);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private int pickColor(String key) {
        final int color = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % NUM_OF_TILE_COLORS;
        try {
            return mColors.getColor(color, Color.BLACK);
        } finally {
            mColors.recycle();
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getCircularBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap output;

        if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
            output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } else {
            output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        float radius = 0;

        if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
            radius = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
        } else {
            radius = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        }

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }
```

It's basically creates a circle with the first letter of the name in the menu. If the `getLetterTile` fails, I want it to set a default method. It can fail if the `displayName` is empty. I have a profile default avatar picture but I want it to be in a circle as the image is not in circle:

[image]

How can I use the default image and set it into the circle?

In the XML:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: there are a couple of github repositories that implement what you need .so try to employ them.

Comment: check this https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: use image loader library. for example, Glide, picasso

Comment: As you can see from the code, I already have a method `getCircularBitmap` to get the Bitmap. I just want it to set an image instead of the letter as default. Without using 3-party libraries or editing the XML.

Answer (score 0):

From XML you said?
Try Below.

```
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            app:cardCornerRadius="35dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_avatar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/pro_pic"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Just incase you don't have, simply add cardView to your gradle, also I don't know if you're on androidX or below, implementation still same anyways.

```
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
```